# maxima tex output to show brackets for sin and cos

Tags: tex, brackets, maxima, trigonometry

I use maxima's tex output and would like to change the way it outputs sin(x).
It currently does:

```
tex(sin(x));
$$\sin x$$
```

But I would like to have brackets around the x, but not always; for instance, if i use this:

```
sin(x/2) already has \left( and \right)
tex(sin(x/2));
\begin{equation} \sin \left({{x}\over{2}}\right) \end{equation}
```

is this possible, maybe with the texput function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you are not adverse to putting in a little Lisp code:

```
(%i1) :lisp (setf (get '%sin 'tex) nil)
(%i1) :lisp (setf (get '%cos 'tex) nil)
```

That takes away the predefined handler function (which treats sin and cos as prefix operators). Then you get:

```
(%i1) tex (sin(x) + cos(y));
$$\cos \left(y\right)+\sin \left(x\right)$$
```

Comment: Thanks Robert. Do you happen to have a similar solution for invisible times: tex(2*x) now becomes 2\,x where I would like 2x?

Comment: Try this: :lisp (setf (get 'mtimes 'texsym) '(" "))

Comment: Great, this works perfectly. Is there also a way to output %i differently from i?

Comment: @mmzc Try this (this is ordinary Maxima input, not Lisp): `texput(%i, "j");` which changes the output to "j" -- of course you can put any string you want.

Comment: @RobertDodier Is it possible to do this via `texput` or is the lisp command the only option?

Comment: (too late to edit previous comment): I found one possible solution, not sure if it's recommended, have added it here, for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

In case your context precludes using `: lisp` an alternative might be to define a function like:

```
psin(x):=sin(x);
psintex:lambda([e],printf(false,"\\sin\\left(~a\\right)", tex1(e)));
texput('psin, psintex);
```

I'm not sure if this kind of aliasing is problematic for programmatic reasons; however, in terms of flexibility for tex output, I find it very useful, as one can access the preferred form simply by switching between `sin(x)` and `psin(x)`.